# FragmentManager in kotlin not recognized

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin

I want in my application to set A viewPager and pager adapter, but I cant implement it because I cant use fragmentManager.
i get the following err:

"Error:(45, 38) Classifier 'FragmentManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here"

my code is:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

private lateinit var pagerAdapter: mPagerAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    pagerAdapter = mPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) // err is here
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
  }

class mPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) :
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {


    // 2
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return Tab1() as Fragment
            1 -> return Tab2() as Fragment
            2 -> return Tab3() as Fragment
        }
        return Tab1() as Fragment
    }

    // 3
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

what should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FragmentManager` is the class name. `fragmentManager`, with a lowercase 'f', is the property reference to the `getFragmentManager()` method.

You want to instead use `supportFragmentManager` (as `getFragmentManager()` returns the Framework `FragmentManager`, not the Support Library `FragmentManager`):

```
pagerAdapter = mPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
```

Comment: thank you thats correct, I also needed to extend from FragmentActivity instead Activity, and that resolved and let me use supportFragmentManager